# Collect key value pair from array of objects Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects in Javascript and I want to collect just the given key and value from the list. How would one do this? I feel like I have over engineered the solution but maybe not.

I wasn't sure if there was a cleaner way of doing this.

The results should be a list of objects containing just the key 'id' and id 'value'.

```js
const items = [{
    id: "45054",
    name: "Brittany"
  },
  {
    id: "8980",
    name: "Amber"
  },
  {
    id: "9843",
    name: "Leslie"
  },
  {
    id: "45306",
    name: "Doug"
  },
  {
    id: "7863",
    name: "Kevin"
  },
]

let ids = []

for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  ids.push({
    id: items[i].id
  })
}

console.log(ids)
```

Comment: If the code works and you're looking for advice on improving it, [codereview.se] is the appropriate place. But see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that isn't bad, I personally would just use map:

```js
let ids = items.map(item => ({id: item.id}));
```

Comment: Or if you want an even shorter notation: `let ids = items.map(item => item.id)`

Comment: @IgnaceVau except that wouldn't give the output the OP needs. That would just be an array, not an array of objects.

Comment: @Andy Right, just noticed

Comment: @IgnaceVau if you really wanted to use something like that then [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and the [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015) could be used: `const ids items.map(({id}) => ({id}));` ️

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner way would be using `Array.prototype.map()`. Your answer is certainly not a wrong way to do so, though.

```js
const items = [{
    id: "45054",
    name: "Brittany"
  },
  {
    id: "8980",
    name: "Amber"
  },
  {
    id: "9843",
    name: "Leslie"
  },
  {
    id: "45306",
    name: "Doug"
  },
  {
    id: "7863",
    name: "Kevin"
  },
]

const ids = items.map(x => ({id: x.id}));
console.log(ids)
```

Answer (score 1):

To deal with this you can use map like Pranev said, but if you want to have a more specific solution based on any other key, you can play with Object.keys, and then use the key that you want to get the id or any other key.

```
    const items = [
  {
    id: "45054",
    name: "Brittany",
  },
  {
    id: "8980",
    name: "Amber",
  },
  {
    id: "9843",
    name: "Leslie",
  },
  {
    id: "45306",
    name: "Doug",
  },
  {
    id: "7863",
    name: "Kevin",
  },
];

let ids = [];

for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  const keys = Object.keys(items[i]);
  keys.forEach((key) => {
    if (key === "id") {
      ids.push({
        id: items[i][key],
      });
    }
  });
}
console.log(ids);
```